# How to use `set term push` and `set term pop` in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am using gnuplot 5.2.7 on Arch Linux. I want to temporarily change the terminal's configuration, plot something, and then restore it (I have no terminal configuration in my initialization file). I think `pop` and `push` can be used to this effect, but I'm having no success.

This is what I do in a gnuplot session. First I set the terminal to `wxt` and push it, then plot a sine wave:

```
gnuplot> set term wxt 1 ; set term push

Terminal type is now 'wxt'
Options are '1 enhanced'
   pushed terminal wxt 1 enhanced
gnuplot> plot sin(x)
```

So far this works. Now I want to temporarily change the background to cyan, and then revert to default background:

```
gnuplot> set term wxt 1 background "cyan"

Terminal type is now 'wxt'
Options are '1 background '#00ffff' enhanced'
gnuplot> plot sin(x)
gnuplot> set term pop
   restored terminal is wxt 1 background '#00ffff' enhanced
gnuplot>
```

As you can see, `pop`ing the terminal didn't restore the background. The next plot comes up with a cyan background.

[Gnuplot's manual (pdf)](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_5.0/gnuplot.pdf) states, in page 257, that:

> The command `set term push` remembers the current terminal including its
>   settings while `set term pop` restores it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm observing the same with gnuplot 5.2.6, Win7. I'm not sure, but it looks like `set term push` and `set term pop` are made for switching between _different_ terminals, not necessarily for the same terminal just with different options.

Comment: @theozh Thanks for checking! I agree that is a possible interpretation of the manual -- I wish it were more precise.

Answer (score 1):

From the gnuplot manual:

> The command set term push remembers the current terminal including its
>   settings while set term pop restores it. This is equivalent to save
>   term and load term, but without accessing the filesystem. Therefore
>   they can be used to achieve platform independent restoring of the
>   terminal after printing, for instance. After gnuplot's startup, the
>   default terminal or that from startup file is pushed automatically.
>   Therefore portable scripts can rely that set term pop restores the
>   default terminal on a given platform unless another terminal has been
>   pushed explicitly.

Actually, it's not completely clear to me what is the benefit of `terminal push` and `terminal pop`? Well, restoring the default terminal. The only advantage I can (currently) think of is that in a long gnuplot script when you are switching back and forth to different terminals you don't have to type in all the parameters of your default terminal again and again. And in case you change some terminal settings you otherwise would have to change all the occurrences in your script.

Maybe the following is useful to you: at the beginning of the code define your terminals with your backgrounds or other settings as string variables and then later call them as macro with `@`. So with this, I don't see a difference between calling `@TerminalDefault` and `set terminal pop`, except that `@TerminalDefault` will also restore if you had the same terminal before but just with different settings.

**Code:**

```
### workaround for terminal push & pop with same terminal but different settings
reset session

TerminalDefault = 'set term wxt 0 background "white"'
TerminalCyan = 'set term wxt 0 background "cyan"'
TerminalYellow = 'set term wxt 0 background "yellow"'
TerminalPNG = 'set term png background "green"'

@TerminalDefault
plot x
pause -1 TerminalDefault

@TerminalCyan
plot x**2
pause -1 TerminalCyan

@TerminalPNG
set output "Test.png"
plot x**3
set output
pause -1 TerminalPNG

@TerminalDefault
plot x**4
pause -1 TerminalDefault

### end of code
```

Comment: You can e.g. have a script, which exports your current plot to a file, like `call 'export.gp' 'output.png'`. This script can then push the current terminal, set its target terminal, plot and at the end restore the previous one.

Comment: @theozh Thanks again for your help. It's not just the background, though: the font and the size are also not always reset either by `set term pop` or `unset term`. I've concluded that it's simply impossible for gnuplot to revert a terminal to its pristine state. I ended up implementing something similar to what you propose: I dug out all the defaults I care about for the terminals I use from the manual, and hard-coded them in a way similar to what you did.

Comment: @theozh: To give more context: I'm the maintainer of a gnuplot front-end for the Julia programming language ([see here](https://github.com/mbaz/Gaston.jl)). The interface is more similar to Matlab than to gnuplot. I want to let my users do things like `plot(x,y); plot(x,y,background="blue"); plot (x,y)` and have the first and last plots have a white background. My solution to this is to restore the terminal defaults (dug out of the manual) for every single plot.