# Get the current output file in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

In gnuplot you can set the output file with [`set output`](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node211.html)`'path/to/file'`. I want to write a short utility script which briefly changes the output to a different file and then resets it.

Since the scripts that use the utility are generated by [`gnuplottex`](https://ctan.org/pkg/gnuplottex), I don't know the name of output files and therefore I can't set the output again.

When you want to briefly change terminal, you can do `set terminal`[`push`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56622130/1137334) before and `set terminal pop` after it. AFAIK there's nothing similar with `set ouptut`.

You can show the current output by [`show`](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node154.html)`output` but it goes directly to stdout I couldn't figure how to save it into a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is the gnuplot variable `GPVAL_OUTPUT`.
type `show var GPVAL` and you will get a list of gnuplot variables.